# Python X is not defined in class

Tags: python, class, nameerror

Every time I try to run my class and test it I just get told x is not defined when it is.

```
import math


class Coordinates():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        "Initializes the constructor"""
        self.__x = x 
        self.__y = y

    def getX(self):
        """Retrieves the x value assigned to constructor"""
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        """Retrieves the y value assigned to constructor"""
        return self.y

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string presentation in the form 
        (x, y)"""
        return "(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"

    def distance(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """Using the distance formula to calculate the distance of
        two constructors of the class"""
        return math.sqrt((self.x2-self.x1)**2 + (self.y2-self.y1)**2)

    def orginDistance(self, x, y):
        """By pluging 0 into the distance formula you can
        find the distance from the orgin"""
        return math.sqrt((0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Allows distances from orgin to be compared"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        if firstEq is secondEq: 
            return True
        else: 
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """Allows for the distances to be compared"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        if firstEq is secondEq:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def _lt__(self, other):
        """compares self to be less than or equal to others orgin distance"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        return firstEq < secondEq

    def __le__(self, other):
        """compares self to be less than or equal to orgin distance of other"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        return firstEq <= secondEq

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """compares self to greater than other in orgin distance"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        return firstEq > secondEq

    def __ge__(self, other):
        """compares orgin distance to find if its greater
        than or equal to the other"""
        firstEq = math.sqrt(0 - self.x)**2 + (0 - self.y)**2
        secondEq = math.sqrt(0 - other.x)**2 + (0 - other.y)**2
        return firstEq >= secondEq

p0 = Coordinates(x,y) 
print(p0)
```

the error is displayed at line of p0. I am not sure why this is happening because in the Coordinates class it is defined.

Comment: Please fix the indentation: select all the code and *type* `ctrl-k`.

Comment: You didn't put anything for `x` or `y` you literally put the **undefined** variables `x` and `y` as is.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] nd the other links on that page, like [mcve].

Comment: Always include the complete Traceback in your question, if there is one. Format the Traceback as code

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't assigned anything to `x` or `y` they don't exist and `Coordinates(x,y)` will produce a NameError.

You defined the `x` and `y` parameters with default values, try:

```
p0 = Coordinates()
```

or

```
x = 3
y = 2
p1 = Coordinates(x,y)
```

---

Even though you gave `x` and `y` default values **in** the class, they are not in the same scope as your `p0 = Coordinates(x,y)` statement.

[4.1 Structure of a program; 4.2 Naming and Binding.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program)

Try this in the Python shell/ide/...

```
>  class A: 
..     a = 2 
..   
>  print(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>  print(A.a)
2
```